# Winforms. Отобразить на графике разрешенные значения

Tags: c#, winforms, диаграммы

Здравствуйте,

Поставил в форме график синуса и так же пытаюсь показать разрешенную площадь значений.
Надо вывести на графике что-то похожее на серый прямоугольник (см. рис. 1) . Он не обязательно начинается с `Y=0`.
Точки синуса приходят во время работы програмы одна за одной.
Пытался использовать `StripLine` - очень похоже на то, что мне надо (см. рис. 2, желтоватая и голубоватая зоны), но у меня не получается определить его начальное значение как точку, в которой две координаты не равны `0`. Так же его продолжительность должна быть не бесконечной. (В отличие от рис. 2)

рис. 1
[image: рис. 1]

рис. 2
[image: рис. 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Благодаря одному из участников английского Stackoverflow, вот он ответ (точнее, работающий код) :

```
void drawAllowedArea(Point startPoint, Point endPoint, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var l = (float)chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(startPoint.X);
    var t = (float)chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(endPoint.Y);
    var r = (float)chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(endPoint.X);
    var b = (float)chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(startPoint.Y);
    var rect = RectangleF.FromLTRB(l, t, r, b);
    using (var br = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Blue)))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height);
    }
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height);
}

//and use this function in chart1_Paint event:
void chart1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    drawAllowedArea(new Point(20, 50000), new Point(40, 100000), e);
}
```

Ссылка на мой вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263864/winforms-chart-draw-a-allowed-area-on-line-chart

Спасибо всем, кто думал как мне помочь! :)